# Merging 2 RxJs observables into a mapped observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, ngrx

any help is appreciated - I am somewhat new to RxJs but i think I have some substantial misunderstanding about how Observables are mapped.

There are two observables that I store via NGRX for one Account a "receivedMessages" and "sentMessages". each is simply an array of "MessageModel" which contains a toUsername and fromUsername.

I'm trying to combine these two observables into 1 observable that I can display "MessageThreads" with all the correspondance between these two users by having an array of such an object with a "username: as unique key almost like a HashMap, this looks like: `{username: string, thread: MessageModel[]}`

I've tried using forkJoins, Concats, Merge but i'm getting a strange error. leading me to think i've probably not understood what ngrx or rxjs is actually doing :(

inbox-container.component.ts

```js
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppState } from 'src/app/store/app.reducers';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { MessageModel } from '../../shared/models/message.model';
import { Observable, forkJoin, of, from, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { map, concat, combineLatest, mergeMap, flatMap, switchMap, mapTo, merge } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { stringify } from '@angular/compiler/src/util';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-inbox-container',
  templateUrl: './inbox-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inbox-container.component.css']
})
export class InboxContainerComponent implements OnInit {

  receivedMessages: Observable<MessageModel[]>;
  sentMessages: Observable<MessageModel[]>;

  uniqueThreads: Observable<{ username: string, thread: MessageModel[] }[]>;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.receivedMessages = this.store.select('inbox', 'receivedMessages');
    this.sentMessages = this.store.select('inbox', 'sentMessages');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.uniqueThreads =
      of(
        forkJoin(
          this.receivedMessages,
          this.sentMessages
        ),
        map((messages: MessageModel[]): Observable<{ username: string, thread: MessageModel[] }[]> => {
          let mergedThreads: { username: string, thread: MessageModel[] }[] = [];
          messages.forEach((message) => {
            let activeThreadFrom = mergedThreads.find(any => any.username === message.fromUsername)
            if (activeThreadFrom === null) {
              mergedThreads.push({ username: message.fromUsername, thread: [message] })
            } else {
              activeThreadFrom.thread.push(message);
            }
            mergedThreads.push(activeThreadFrom);

            let activeThreadTo = mergedThreads.find(any => any.username === message.toUsername)
            if (activeThreadTo === null) {
              mergedThreads.push({ username: message.toUsername, thread: [message] })
            } else {
              activeThreadTo.thread.push(message);
            }
            mergedThreads.push(activeThreadTo)

          })
          return of(
            mergedThreads
          )
        }
        )
      )
  }

}
```

inbox-container.component.html

```html
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="list-group">
      <a class="list-group-item" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="compose">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
          <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-right: 10px; padding-right:10px;" class="dropdown" appSearchBarDirective
            [text]=searchText.value>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username.." aria-label="Search" #searchText>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <app-reactive-accounts-search [searchForm]=searchText.value></app-reactive-accounts-search>
            </div>
          </div>
        </h4>
      </a>
      <div class="list-group">
        <div class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let thread of ( uniqueThreads | async)" appHighlightDirective
          style="cursor: pointer;">
          <div class="list-group-item-heading">
            <h4>{{ thread.username }}
              <div class="badge pull-right">4</div>
            </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button (click) = "wtf()">asdasd</button>
</div>
```

I'm getting a error in the console logs:

```
InboxContainerComponent.html:10 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'function mapOperation(source) {
        if (typeof project !== 'function') {
            throw new TypeError('argument is not a function. Are you looking for `mapTo()`?');
        }
        return source.lift(new MapOperator(project, thisArg));
    }' of type 'mapOperation'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:3184)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22101)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23362)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23324)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23958)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23918)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (InboxContainerComponent.html:16)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23910)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23306)
    at callViewActi
```

And also a warning in the IDE:

```
Type 'Observable<Observable<[MessageModel[], MessageModel[]]> | OperatorFunction<MessageModel[], Observable<{ username: string; thread: MessageModel[]; }[]>>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<{ username: string; thread: MessageModel[]; }[]>'.
  Type 'Observable<[MessageModel[], MessageModel[]]> | OperatorFunction<MessageModel[], Observable<{ username: string; thread: MessageModel[]; }[]>>' is not assignable to type '{ username: string; thread: MessageModel[]; }[]'.
    Type 'Observable<[MessageModel[], MessageModel[]]>' is missing the following properties from type '{ username: string; thread: MessageModel[]; }[]': l
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

-- SOLUTION ---

I just tied into NGRX store state and as the answer said there is no need to create additional observables.

```js
 init() {
    this.uniqueThreads = this.store.select('inbox').pipe(
      map((state: fromInbox.State) => {
        return [
          state.receivedMessages,
          state.sentMessages
        ]
      }),
      ).pipe(
        map(([receivedMessages, sentMessages]) => {
          let mergedThreads: {username: string, thread: { message: MessageModel, received: boolean }[]}[] = [];
          const messages: MessageModel[] = [...receivedMessages, ...sentMessages];
          messages.forEach((message) => {
            console.log(message)
            let activeThreadFrom = mergedThreads.find(any => any.username === message.fromUsername)
            if (activeThreadFrom === undefined) {
              mergedThreads.push({ username: message.fromUsername, thread: [{message: message, received: true}] })
            } else {
              activeThreadFrom.thread = [ ...activeThreadFrom.thread, {message: message, received: true}];
            };

            let activeThreadTo = mergedThreads.find(any => any.username === message.toUsername)
            if (activeThreadTo === undefined) {
              mergedThreads.push({ username: message.toUsername, thread: [{message: message, received: false}] })
            } else {
              activeThreadTo.thread = [ ...activeThreadTo.thread, {message: message, received: false}];
            }
          })
          console.log(mergedThreads)
          return mergedThreads;
        })
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I don't see any reason to use `of` here and you are using `forkJoin` and `map`  wrong inside it, when you combine two or more observables via `forkJoin` it already returns an observable so you can use `.pipe` on it and do map inside it, see my example

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.uniqueThreads =
    forkJoin(
      this.receivedMessages,
      this.sentMessages
    ).pipe(
      map(([receivedmessages, sentMessages]): Observable<{ username: string, thread: MessageModel[] }[]> => {
        let mergedThreads: { username: string, thread: MessageModel[] }[] = [];
        const messages: MessageModel[] = [...receivedmessages, ...sentMessages];
        messages.forEach((message) => {
          let activeThreadFrom = mergedThreads.find(any => any.username === message.fromUsername)
          if (activeThreadFrom === null) {
            mergedThreads.push({ username: message.fromUsername, thread: [message] })
          } else {
            activeThreadFrom.thread.push(message);
          }
          mergedThreads.push(activeThreadFrom);

          let activeThreadTo = mergedThreads.find(any => any.username === message.toUsername)
          if (activeThreadTo === null) {
            mergedThreads.push({ username: message.toUsername, thread: [message] })
          } else {
            activeThreadTo.thread.push(message);
          }
          mergedThreads.push(activeThreadTo)
        })
        return mergedThreads;
      })
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I ended up using an approach similar to your and just linked into the NgRx state updates rather than create my own observable